# How can I upload a Drupal Website into Wampserver

Tags: database

Someone built me a website a year ago. I want to upload this website into a local wampserver so I can make changes before going live. I need step by step instructions on how to upload the files.

Thank you.

Comment: A simple google search or visiting the [installation](http://drupal.org/documentation/install) pages would help you with that

Answer (score 1):

1. install wamp
2. create folder for your site in wamp/www and upload all files there
3. go to phpmyadmin (`http://localhost/phpmyadmin`) and create database
4. import the sql dump to your db
5. go to wamp/www/your_site/sites/default and change db settings in settings.php , set db name, db user, password and host(localhost)
6. you can see your site here `http://localhost/your_site`